# How to add rss feed to website

Tags: rss, xml

Actually, i want to add rss feed to my website which can be read by google reader. For this what all should i do? I use php to create my website and i am totally new to xml and rss. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an RSS generator such as http://feedity.com/

Or code one your self to output the RSS in XML format http://www.mnot.net/rss/tutorial/